# What service do you use to manage DNS?

Tags: domain-name-system, internal-dns, dns-hosting

What service do you use to manage your DNS? I don't really want to use the DNS manager that is provided with website hosting company. Is there any reliable and fast DNS manager service?

I found a lot while Googling, but I don't know which one I should used. Any recommendation?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

We use [DNS Made Easy](http://www.dnsmadeeasy.com/). We had another provider for several years with less than enticing service. After switching to these guys, with their 100% SLA, we've not ever had a single problem. High priority tickets were responded to < 5 mins, 'normal' tickets ~ 20 minutes.

They've always been courtious and helpful, even when I'm having a blonde day and ask some downright stupid questions.

Comment: They seem to be one of the cheaper DNS providers with global Anycast Routing...
http://www.dnsmadeeasy.com/s0306/res/ipanycast.html

Comment: All their nameservers seem to be located in the USA, which is not recommended if you want a low latency global reach. Also, people should rely on the DNS failover feature as it's not as reliable as it seems. However, it should help in minimizing downtime instead of eliminating it.

Comment: Most of their nameservers are in the USA.  But they also have locations in UK, Germany, and Hong Kong.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a fan of `vi`, myself.

Comment: We run our own BIND 9 servers and vi + restarting BIND is what does it for me.

Comment: "restarting bind"... `rndc reload <domain>` ftw!

Comment: +1 s/vi/emacs/. I *like* the ~ files: they give me something to diff.

Answer (score 2):

The best option is to go with geographically dispersed nameservers (with the use of anycast) if speed is the most important part, otherwise just add a few free nameservers (use google) and share secondary DNS with a few other sysadmins.

As for a commercial DNS provider, easydns.com has always been my first choice.

Comment: +1 easyDNS They are not cheap, but they are pro. I also personally like their admin interface a lot.

Comment: They are not really expensive either when you compare them to domain registrars asking $30 (or even euros!) for a com/net/org domain and just offering some local nameservers. Of course you pay for this kind of quality.

Answer (score 1):

[www.afraid.org](http://afraid.org) gets my vote every time. and its free for most use.

Comment: +1 I was just looking for backup DNS options, and this looks perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I second [DNS Made Easy](http://www.dnsmadeeasy.com), Have used them for a few years now and have not had a single issue.

Answer (score 0):

easydns.com works fine too.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Zonomi's DNS hosting service][1] for some domains (and in fact wrote the app).

I think you're actually fine using your hosting providers DNS service (if they offer one).  Since it can be easier for them to help you, for example, if your IP address changes.

I *would* however recommend you keep your domain *registrar* separate from your hosting company.  Since the registrar is where you can control the name server records.  Which lets you change away from your hosting company, should that become necessary.  And (depending on how unethical your hosting provider is) you don't want them being your registrar and holding your domain hostage.

[1]: http://zonomi.com"Zonomi's DNS hosting service"